# Simple Coded UI login test on remote server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I used Microsoft Test Manager to create a test for a log on page (not locally hosted) and recorded this. All steps were executed without errors.

- Then I've created a Coded UI test project in Visual Studio 2013.
- I added a Coded UI Test with the existing recording.
- I ran the test and I got the message below:

`"FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "` on the username field.

I received this message when using the existing recording, but also if I record using the recording function in Visual Studio.

Has someone got experience with Coded UI Tests and maybe give me an example as to how to set it up.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You "create a (successful) Coded UI test" and it fails. You also say "This happens ... also with manual tests". If a manual test fails then why would you expect an automated version of the same to pass? What is the relevance of the testing with MTM? If you generated a Coded UI test from an MTM recording then say so clearly in the question. If you did do that then how did you check that the original MTM test logged in successfully? Please only ask one question per Stackoverflow question.

Comment: I created a test in MTM and recorded it. The recording was successful, because the playback worked in MTM.
In Visual Studio I created a Coded UI test from the existing recording. 
It was successfully created.
Then I ran the test. This failed.

This was all before the manual test. I created the manual test because I thought the outcome could differ from automated test.
I'm sorry for the confusing question. I followed tutorials and read about setting up Coded UI Tests, but that was equally confusing for me as they didn't seem to meet my requirements.

Comment: Your question plus comment is still very confusing. Please edit the question to explain clearly what you have done, what outcome you expected, what happened and why it is not what you wanted. Questions that are not clear are likely to be deleted.

Comment: I've changed the description. Thanks so far for the feedback. I haven't got much experience with posting issues on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're basically trying to have Coded UI input a value into an HtmlInput control that's a text box on a web page.  The error message `"FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value"` normally means that the value you're trying to submit isn't able to be taken by the control, either because a value isn't accepted (example, numeric values in a name field) or because it's more characters than can be accepted by the field.  It could also be that the recording isn't defining the object properly, and that the property `Text` isn't an option on the control that was found.

So, confirm these three things:

1. The control you're tying to send value to is actually an HtmlInput.  You can't send the Text property to, for example, an `HtmlDiv`.

2. The value you're submitting is a valid value for your control (you're not trying to submit numbers, for example, into a field that won't accept them).

3. The value you're submitting is within the length limit for the field.

If I were a betting man, I would say that you probably don't have the object defined properly.  Take a look at the SearchProperties of the control in question first and make sure that it matches the HTML on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do I need to set a standard environment for testing on an other server.
I develop the Coded UI test project in a workspace on a development environment, but I need the tests to be run on a acceptation environment (the recorded tests are executed on the acceptation environment).

I read it's easy to setup this environment though, but what is best practise?
Is it better to execute it on the same environment?

Here's a code snippet:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestLogonToAccount()
    {
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        this.UIMap.Enterusername();
        this.UIMap.Enterpassword();
        this.UIMap.Clickonlogin();
        this.UIMap.ClickonCentral();
        this.UIMap.Searchforemailaddress();
        this.UIMap.Clickonlogin1();
    }
```

I forgot an important part regarding the login recording test in MTM.
I just tried to play the steps again and got this error:

> ```
> Playback of the selected sections of the action recording could not be completed The playback failed to find the control with the
> ```
>
> given search properties. Additional Details:  TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
>   Name:  '' ClassName:  'MozillaWindowClass' ControlType:  'Window'

Comment: Alright...I need to add the step of starting the browser in my test. Also I've added parameters and a wait. I've noticed that Internet Explorer only works for me.